# how to call handler of fragment class from Broadcast receiver class to update main thread?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-handler

I want to update myfragment thread by calling myfunction that implements handler.But I don't know how to access this handler from broadcast receiver class.Can anyone help me in this?

Fragment Class Code:

```
    Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,42);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(),NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id",R.id.notification_imageView);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =  
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("DEBUG==> Instantiating Alarm Manager Service");
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 
    02,pendingIntent);
```

Implementing the handler to update ui(in fragment class)

```
       public void myfunction()
       {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageView img;

                View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.Sample, null);
                img = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


                Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.5, 0); 
                animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second--2 minutes
                animation.setRepeatCount(200);
                img.startAnimation(animation);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 100000);
            }
            }, 100000);
           }
```

BroadcastReceiever Class --ClassNotificationActivity.class

```
  public class NotificationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private View view;
  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ///How to call handler myfunction from here
      }
         }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

 <receiver  android:name=".view.ui.NotificationActivity" />
```

Comment: you init fragment inside NotificationActivity right? show me your code you execute fragment transaction?

Comment: public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements Injectable {                             @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); ....                                           
 some code

Comment: OnActivity created is inside the Sample Fragment class that is having Alarm Logic